# Output of f_classif (sklearn) is a array that contain nan only

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I used train_test_split to split training set call X_train and y_train. For X_train, I got 799 rows and 9 features. For y_train, it got 799 rows that is the 'changes'. When I try to use `F,PV = f_classif(X, y)` to get F-value. It is correct to have 9 values for 9 features, but it is 'nan'. I just don't understand why I cannot get any output. 
I double check the shape of X_train and y_train.

```
X_train:(799, 9)
y_train:(799,)
```

Which should be correct.

**Output:**

```
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

What's wrong for what I have done?
And I tried to find a solution on Google. Some people say that it should be label but not value. What is that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Number of observations of classes in features may not be sufficiant to make calculations. Assume 'M' is a class in feature1. Since you split your dataset, 'M' might be left in the other part of the dataset. So X_train does not have sufficiant number of 'M' class. Each class should be appear with other classes in other features. You can check that with `value_counts` method if you use pandas.

You can find a example in the link below.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102853-why-do-i-recieve-nan-s-in-the-anova-table-when-i-try-to-analyze-my-data-using-the-statistics-toolbox

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But It may not the case that cause my problem. It is because I am working on an assignment in my study about machine learning. The dataset is provided by the professor. And I have done some question about linear regression and plot some graph that same as the target output. So the dataset itself should not be the problem.